# Main thread not getting stopped in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, runloop

I am developing a desktop-based application in xcode4 that uploads files to ftp, flickr etc. I use multi threading while uploading. I need to cancel the entire uploads going on. Multithreading is done using "`performselectorOnMainthread`". So I need to cancel each of these runloops from the main thread. I even tried  "`CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetMain());`" to cancel the main thread itself, but I amnot getting any result.

Comment: have you tried `+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument`?

Comment: `performSelectorOnMainThread:` is not multithreading. Multithreading involves the creation of *another* thread, either directly or through an NSOperationQueue or GCD dispatch queue.

Comment: Why would you want to cancel the main thread?! Take a look at the [Cocoa Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/).

Comment: You should read [threading programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1)